# Как использовать ответ POST запроса на странице

Tags: javascript

Отправляю POST запрос на сервер для создания элемента на странице. В ответ получаю ID элемента, а также уже созданный элемент(его создает сервер)

```js
form.addEventListener('submit', (e)=>{
    e.preventDefault();
    const formData = new FormData(form);
    formData.append("id", ID);

    fetch('url', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: formData
    })
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(res => {
        console.log(res);
    });
});
```

Как использовать этот полученный ID потом чтобы можно было при клике на элемент переходить на другую страницу, благодаря этому же ID?

Answer (score 0):

Необходимо добавить событие onclick данному элементу, когда добавите его древо элементов, внутри callback-а уже использовать полученный `ID` нужным вам образом (переход по ссылке).

Если вернулся элемент `a`, то после добавления его в древо, обновить у него атрибут `href` на нужным вам с использованием `ID`